# Windows 8 Consumer Preview won't get past login screen

Tags: windows-8-preview, login-screen

I downloaded the Windows 8 Consumer Preview and everything seemed to load fine, except when I try and sign on it says "Welcome" and then restarts itself back to the sign on.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the same hardware conditions you were when you installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on your PC? I got a similar problem when try to boot up Windows 8 with new hardware devices attached. Removing them, then reboot and let Windows 8 detect the devices with plug & play worked.